# Entry to the US with a petty theft record

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, criminal-records

About a year ago I committed a petty theft in a store in my home country, the amount of things stolen was less than 10 USD. I was given a fine and never served jail time. Am I inadmissible to the US as a foreign Master's student or skilled worker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most questions regarding study and work abroad belong on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com), but the statutory grounds of inadmissibility apply equally to those categories and to visitors.

A petty theft as described in the question does not trigger the statutory grounds of inadmissibility ([8 USC 1182(a)(2)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_2_A)), but it will present an obstacle that you will probably have trouble overcoming so soon after the conviction.  This history could lead a visa officer or immigration officer to doubt your credibility or the good faith of your application.  For an offence of this nature, the magnitude of this obstacle may be small, but a prudent visa applicant in your shoes should consider engaging an immigration lawyer, who should be able to help you address your history without appearing desperate.

Comment: +1 however I disagree with `consider engaging an immigration lawyer, who should be able to help you address your history without appearing desperate.`

Comment: For most people the cost of an immigration lawyer is out of reach. For a petty theft offense with value less than $10 USD, if I were him I would have all my discharge papers and a succinct explanation ready and then roll the dice by going for the interview myself.

Comment: @TheZealot maybe you are aware about conditions of applying for Canadian or Aussie/NZ visa with this record? As far as I understand, for Canada, no matter how small is the amount stolen, I still need a temporary residence permit, though maybe it will go as summary offence, and in this case I don't need it.

If I get the citizenship of another country and apply for US or Canadian visa as a citizen of that country, would US/Canadian authorities somehow be able see my record from previous country?

Comment: @phoog maybe you could tell, about the comment above?

Comment: Your record is your record, regardless of citizenship.  Lying about your record is a huge risk: in many countries it can make you permanently inadmissible.  It seems that taking such a huge risk over a minor offence would be very foolish.

Comment: @phoog I don't know if there's a question about a particular crime in Canadian visa application; however, they require a certificate from the police. Then it is not considered lying, since I did not deceive the visa officer, and gave him/her a valid certificate from police that I have no criminal record. I do not see here anything that can be considered deceiving a visa officer. It largely depends what will the visa officer ask.

Comment: @HypeTotec Visa applications almost invariably ask about prior criminal records.

Comment: @TheZealot however, they rarely ask about the time of crime. According to Canadian immigration rules, a crime is deemed pardoned if more than 10 years passed since. If I check the blank near "have some criminal record" but my certificate from police is clean, they may automatically assume that my crime is more than 10 years old

Comment: @HypeTotec It appears you want to lie to them.

Comment: @HypeTotec I am not saying that you have lied or will lie. I'm just saying that you should not lie. Whether you are required to mention your record will depend on the question being asked. The US, for example, asks different questions for different immigration benefits. Naturalization questions are broader than for immigration, which in turn are broader than for nonimmigrants. If the question is "have you ever been arrested" then they expect you to answer in the affirmative even if you were never charged; if "ever convicted" they expect "yes" even if your record was expunged.

Comment: @HypeTotec but often the question will be qualified with "for a crime that..." (and then they will mention some criteria relating to crimes of moral turpitude).  If the question is qualified in that way, you probably do not have to respond with reference to the petty theft and can answer "no."

Comment: @phoog but what I thought is that naturalization does not have a universal question list, the questions depend on record (including criminal if exists) during the 5 years in the USA..

Comment: @HypeTotec I'm referring to the questions on the application form.  The questions asked by the interviewer will indeed depend on the answers given on the form, as well as evidence uncovered by investigation.  As I recall, the questions on the form are of the "have you ever been arrested" variety.